# mod_rewrite where the search begins?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Recently, I'm experimenting with PHP's mod_rewrite engine. A bunch of tutorials I've read gave me a pretty good picture how to use its most basic and useful possibilities. But there is still that question I didn't find the answer for. I guess it should be the very first question to be explained but no tutorial gave me the answer yet.

I'm wondering **which very part of URL** is being considered when trying to match the regex.

Let's say I have a directory `my_project` on my server and a `.htaccess` file inside that directory. The browser should see the directory like this:

```
http://my_website.com/my_project
```

If I add a rule in `.htaccess` then which part of the above URL will be considered when trying to match the regex of this rule? I'm pretty good in understanding regular expressions themselves but I can't figure out which chunk of URL does mod_rewrite pick to do the regex.

If my question isn't clear enough let me also put it this way: which exact place of the above URL is matched by the following regex in `.htaccess`?

```
^
```

Yet another question, if I go to

```
http://my_website.com/my_project/subfolder
```

will the considered part of the URL will be different or it will always depend on the place where `.htaccess` is placed?

Comment: mod_rewrite is an *Apache* module and has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: @deceze, good point. It's always difficult for me to isolate these two things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.
To explain the problem and how I got to the answer I'll try to explain it step by step.
Let's assume the following:

`.htaccess` is placed in a folder `my_project` in the root path of `www.my_website.com`.  `.htaccess` consists the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?matched=$0
```

To avoid endless loop let's "fire" the rule only if we provide a *test* parameter in query string, so the complete `.htaccess` should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} test=1
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?matched=$0
```

Now, if everything goes as I thought we should end up in the `index.php` script placed in `my_project` folder. To see the whole match let's add the following line to the script:

```
var_dump($_GET["matched"]);
```

In the browser we go to `http://my_website.com/my_project?test=1` and we expect the output to be:

```
string(32) "http://my_website.com/my_project"
```

But it is not! It is instead

```
string(0) ""
```

We're almost there. Now let's go to `http://my_website.com/my_project/subfolder/?test=1`. The output is

```
string(10) "subfolder/"
```

That proves one thing - when mod_rewrite starts to compare the URL with regular expressions it doesn't see the `PROTOCOL` part of the URL as well as the `HTTP_HOST` part. As my further research reveal, it also ommits every folder above the `.htaccess` location as well as the query string and hash part of the URL. For the mod_rewrite the URL begins where the `.htaccess` location begins.

I hope this self-answered question will be helpful for someone in the future.

Enjoy!

Comment: +1 for answering your own question with a nice explanation. One thing I would like to note is that the information you concluded too is the mentioned in the documentation of `RewriteRule` but not that clear. Also all `RewriteRule`s ignore the schema and the host name of the URL and not just the .htaccess ones.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a practical example

Suppose Your website is www.example.com and  it's located in a folder/Directory named 'ex' 
You'll place the .htaccess file in your ex folder to make it work  for your website www.example.com

Now  let's say  you want to make this url clean  www.example.com/ex/index.php?page=welcome

open your.htaccess file that you have placed in your ex folder and add this following code to it

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-+_%*?]+)/?$    index.php?page=$1     [L]
```

It'll chagle the URL from www.example.com/ex/index.php?page=welcome to www.example.com/ex/welcome

Now let's say you moved your website to a subfolder ex/subfolder OR www.example.com/ex to www.example.com/ex/subfolder

Simply move the .htaccess file with all of your site to that subfolder no need to change the code it'll work the same

([A-Za-z0-9-+_%*?]+) <-- this part with in the brackets is used as regular expression 
means you are looking for any Character from A to z and from a to z and any number from 0 to 9  and symbol - , +,_,%,*,? and the + sign after the closing square bracket means  more than  one .

In short You are asking to for which is ([in here]+) and it's more than one ,if however you remove the + symbol after the bracket  it'll return only the first character

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the answer I was looking for. I understand how mod_rewrite works. I just can't figure out which part of the URL is treated as the string for regex.

Comment: ([A-Za-z0-9-+_%*?]+) <--  this part  with in the brackets is used as regular expression (edited the answer  hope it'll help you now )

Comment: I finally figured it out by myself. If the whole URL was considered in the comparison then your regex wouldn't match that URL because the URL consist e.g. a **dot** sign. Now I know that only a part of the URL is compared by the regex and it is the path where the `.htaccess` is placed. That means the protocol and http_host is ommited. Also folders superior to `.htaccess` are ommited. I hope you understand my point of view.